# Ubuntu encryptfs-mount-private not working

Tags: ubuntu, passwords, ecryptfs

Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Ran some updates, finally got around to rebooting.

When I rebooted, It came up with Some errors about missing files, etc...

Came to discover my home directory was not decrypted.  I simply had a readme file that said to run "encryptfs-mount-private".

When I do it doesn't tell me the passphrase is incorrect, it tells me

```
Inserted auth tok with sig [xxxxxxxxxx] into the user session keyring
You do not own that encrypted directory
```

and I do own it.  If I put in a different pass it tells me it's incorrect, I'm logging in fine, but my home directory is remaining encrypted.

Help?

Answer (score 1):

A possible problem is that your user might not own the hidden `/home/<username>/.ecryptfs` directory, so can't read the encrypted files to decrypt.

Solution there is to ensure your user has ownership of that file:

```
$ sudo chown -r <username>:<username> ~/.ecryptfs
$ ecryptfs-mount-private
```